# Trying to open plist file to read ShadowHashData but keep getting an error ("the domain/default pair... does not exist")

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, plist, domain

I am trying to run a command to try and look at a plist file on my computer, so I type this into terminal:

```
cd /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"
```

and then

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<username>.plist ShadowHashData
```

However, whenever I do this, I get this result:

```
The domain/default pair of (/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<username>.plist, ShadowHashData) does not exist
```

This might be a simple question, but I really want to run this command and I don't know how why the command doesn't work. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `cd /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"` as you are including the _fully qualified pathname_ of the `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$USER.plist` _file_. If I open **Terminal** and use, literally, `sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$USER.plist ShadowHashData` it outputs what's expected, `<hex data>`, where _hex data_ forms a plist file.

Comment: I tried typing it without the cd command but it still didn’t work, it gave me the error message instead :/ @user3439894

Comment: @CJK, The _file_ does exist on my system and `sudo` is needed as the `../Default/` _directory_ is owned by `root`.

Comment: @CJK so which exact commands should I write into Terminal?

Comment: See @user3439894’S first comment.  It explicitly dictates the command to type into Terminal.